# I get mousedown w/ finger on my mouse+touch PC (I need touchstart)

Tags: javascript, touch, mouseevent

Why my all-in-one PC (with touch-screen) returns a **`mousedown` event**, in place of `touchstart`**, when I TAP the screen** ?

My javascript code works perfectly:

- on PCs (with `hover`)
- on mobiles and tablets (with big buttons)

Nota:

- I took care of testing touch/mouse on EVERY event (theres's no `if(isTouchDevice)`)
- I need to test `if(event.type == 'touchstart')` to adapt my code (ex: `hover` or not)

But with my mouse+touchscreen PC, I only get "mouse" events (when I click AND when I tap). Why?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found something by myself :

1. In my code, `event.type` returned the LAST event fired (`mousedown`), because the function was launched twice. Why ? Because, on mouse+touch PCs, 2 events fire
   simultaneously while touch-screen: `touchstart + mousedown`. (and only one: `mousedown` when mouse click). See http://jsfiddle.net/z5cygsb4/2/
2. The solution : `e.preventDefault();` See https://jsfiddle.net/qjqcerok/
3. But sometimes, it doesn't work. So, you have to use `document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, { passive: false } );` See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9809